# Include handlebars partial dynamically

Tags: node.js, npm, handlebars.js, require-handlebars

I have 4 files: main.hbs, partial1.hbs, partial2.hbs, app.js

in partial1.hbs

```
{{#partial 'test'}}
    THIS IS TEST
{{/partial}}
```

in partial2.hbs

```
{{#partial 'hello'}}
THIS IS HELLO
{{/partial}}
```

in main.hbs

```
{{#block 'test'}}this is a placeholder{{/block}}
{{#block 'hello'}}this is also a placeholder{{/block}}
```

in app.js

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      path = require('path');


//adding handlebars
var exphbs  = require('express3-handlebars');
var helpers = require('../handlebarsHelpers');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', 
                            helpers: helpers,
                            precompiled: ['views/partials'],
                            extname: '.hbs', partialsDir: ['views/partials']}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

function loadPartial(name){
var partial = Handlebars.partials[name];
    if(typeof partial === "string"){
        partial = Handlebars.compile(partial);
        Handlebars.partials[name] = partial;
    }
    return partial;
};

Handlebars.registerHelper("block", function(name, options){
    var partial = loadPartial(name) || options.fn;
    return partial(this, { data:options.hash });
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("partial", function(name, options){
    Handlebars.registerPartial(name, options.fn);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('main');
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

module.exports = app;
```

Issues:
I’m not able to replace the block on main.hbs by the appropriate partial block. Can you guys help?

P.S: I don’t want to use {{> partialName}} to include the partial but instead have something like a json and then render dynamically the block.

Comment: This seems like a very confusing approach. What is wrong with regularly registered partials?